# Laravel Error Syntax error or access violation in DB::raw

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to get agama with the count of pegawai with same as propinsisID and agamaID this is my controller, but i get this error Error Syntax error or access violation 
Please help me.. Sorry for Bad English

```
public function getPropinsi($id)
{
    $this->data['query'] =  DB::table("propinses")->where("id",$id)->first();
    $this->data['title'] = $this->data['query']->Propinsi;
    $this->data['count_satker'] = DB::table('satkerfakes')->where('PropinsiID',$id)->count(); 
    $this->data['pegawai'] = Pegawais::where('PropinsiID',$id);
    $this->data['agama'] = DB::table("agamas")
                                    ->select("agamas.Agama",DB::raw("(select count(*) 
                                        from pegawais 
                                        where pegawais.PropinsiID = $id
                                        where pegawais.AgamaID = agamas.AgamaID) as total_pegawai"))->get();
    return view('index.propinsi',$this->data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have at least 2 errros here:

```
$this->data['pegawai'] = Pegawais::where('PropinsiID',$id);
```

What yo want to achieve here? If you want to get record with this id, you should use:

```
$this->data['pegawai'] = Pegawais::where('PropinsiID',$id)->get();
```

or

```
$this->data['pegawai'] = Pegawais::where('PropinsiID',$id)->first();
```

depending whether you want to get 1 record or more.

And in your query you use:

```
select count(*)  from pegawais 
    where pegawais.PropinsiID = $id
    where pegawais.AgamaID = agamas.AgamaID) as total_pegawai
```

You cannot user `where` twice, you should use `AND` operator:

```
select count(*)  from pegawais 
    where pegawais.PropinsiID = $id
    AND pegawais.AgamaID = agamas.AgamaID) as total_pegawai
```